# Return a reference on a string using an iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

I have a vector containing strings, an iterator (`_it`) on this vector, and I would like to return a reference on one of the string using this iterator.

For now, the return is made by copy:

```
std::string myClass::next_token()
{
  std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator old_it = _it++;
  return *old_it;
}
```

I would like to do this (note the `&` on return-type)

```
std::string& myClass::next_token() 
{
//...
}
```

But I get the following error :

> invalid initialization of reference of type `‘std::string& {aka
>   std::basic_string<char>&}’` from expression of type `‘const
>   std::basic_string<char>’ std::string& token = *old_it`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `const_iterator` will never get you a non-`const` reference; you need to either use a plain `iterator` or return a `const string &`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a `string&` from a `const string &` as the `const string &` is not modifiable.  The reason you are getting a `const string &` is that you are using a `const_iterator`.  If you change you code to

```
std::string& myClass::next_token()
{
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator old_it = _it++;
    return *old_it;
}
```